# Linked List append method

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm a python programmer who is fairly new to C++, and I'm trying to write a linked list for the first time.

My book has me writing it like this...

```
ListNode *node, *newNode = new ListNode(x);
if (head_ != NULL) {
    node = _find (size_ - 1);
    node->link_ = newNode;
}
else {
    head_ = newNode;
}
size_ += 1;
```

this makes sense, but it seems more complicated then my initial approach of...

```
void LList::append(ItemType x)
{
    ListNode *node=head_, *newNode = new ListNode(x);
    while (node->link_ != NULL) {
        node = node->link_;
    }
    node->link_ = newNode;
    size_ += 1;
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an odd message when I try to run this on X-Code for Mac OSx Mountain lion.

```
Thread: 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x8)
```

Could anyone explain to me what this means?

Comment: I may have just figured it out.  Could it possibly be because I set node = head_, but since nothing is in head_ yet the program is confused??

Comment: Be aware that you can just use `std::list`. And that very few do. `std::vector` is generally faster and more convenient...

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Not even once

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Lol! Oops! I don't know where the "od" went. Lol

Comment: Also, be aware that updating a list `size` incrementally, for each operation, precludes having constant time list splice operations. At least with convenient interface. And given that splicing is just about the only operation that lists can do better than vectors, doing the incremental update is not necessarily a good idea, even if `std::list` does that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list is empty, `head_` is NULL or uninitialized, and your code doesn't check for that possibility. Your code will try to read `head_->link_`, which isn't allocated, throwing a memory access error.

Comment: +1 sounds about right. another possibility is that `head_` isn't even initialized.

Comment: @unsigned I replaced it with this, and I still get an error code.  This time in a completely different method that worked before!

Comment: Think i figured it out! Thank you!!

Comment: Last question... is there anything inherently wrong with the way I wrote it (once it works).  Is there any reason I would want to use the book's method rather than my way?

Comment: @AshleyElisabethStallings Assuming it's a simple linked list, and `_find` is not making use of any special indexing, your list traversal should be functionally equivalent, *provided* you properly check for an empty list, which your code posted above does not.

Comment: Okay just making sure! Like I said, I'm pretty new to C++, so I wasn't sure if there was anything reason I was unaware of to call the find method rather than just traverse the list to the end.  Thanks so much :)